# Where I can find Specific PIDs list for Hyundai Motor and Mitsubishi Motor?

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, mitsubishi, pid

I am looking for specific PIDs for Hyundai and Mitsubishi vehicles. Can you tell where I can find Specific PIDs list for Hyundai Motor and Mitsubishi Motor?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it you're looking for manufacturer specific pids? IOW, not the standard pids?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes. only for manufacturer specific pids.

Comment: Have you checked with Hyundai and Mitsubishi?

Comment: A google search gave this as the third result : https://www.outilsobdfacile.com/data-trouble-code-obd2.php

Comment: Depending on year and type of these cars what manufacturer specific codes are available, you question is too broad.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks. But I am seeking PID not the DTC code.

Comment: @Moab yes. especially Mitsubishi triton or Hyundai iLoad, years doesn't matter..